# Java on the Mac, as evt.iscontroldown evt.iscommanddown all?

Tags: java, macos, keyevent

Press controll + w I want to be the end of the program
but Case by Mac
Press command+w end of the program
use method

```
public  void startKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt){
    System.out.println(evt.getKeyCode());

    if(evt.isControlDown()&&evt.getKeyCode()==87)
    {
            System.exit(0);

    }
```

but

```
public  void startKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt){
    System.out.println(evt.getKeyCode());

    if(evt.isCommandDown()&&evt.getKeyCode()==87)
    {
            System.exit(0);

    }
```

This function does not exist 
evt.isCommandDown()  Is there something that acts like a controll?

Answer (score 2):

In OSX the command key functions as the Meta key. Use [`KeyEvent.isMetaDown()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#isMetaDown%28%29) instead.

Comment: You can accept my answer as the answer that helped you. Click the tick below the score of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC The Cmd key should work as the ctrl key on mac by default - you don't need to change anything to get this behavior.